# geoserver 2.8 - layer not queryable

Tags: geoserver, wms

I am cascading a WMS and adding a polygon-layer on top of it. While this is working in geoserver 2.18, our operational system is still using geoserver 2.8.

The problem occurs in layer preview, when I try to click on the layers I get an error message: The Layer is not queryable.

I reproduced it on my localhost using both 2.8 and 2.18 (where it worked)

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1">
    <ServiceException code="OperationNotSupported" locator="QUERY_LAYERS"> Layer bplan:bplan is not queryable </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

This is the error message.

I added both layers to a layer group and enabled querying in the layers itself. In geoserver 2.8 there is no possibility to check "queryable" for the layer group (at least I did not find one).

Someone has an idea how to do it? Upgrading our geoserver would be my move, but my boss does not want us to do this.

Comment: Upgrading is the way to go, it takes next to no time and will give you improved security as well as new features like this

Comment: This is basically what I will tell him tomorrow. I would have to add a lot of stuff we are curretnly running on the old one on the new one but I think that it would still be faster than trying to solve this problem.

Comment: Data directory should move across with no changes

Comment: Thanks a lot btw! It worked so far, at least to some extent.